# Receives always null message while trying to read a message from MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I try to receive the message from the MQ.
I can able to see the messages in the MQ Explorer.
But i cant able to get the messages. It always return null.
But i can able to drop message to the Queue.

The code is here.

```
 MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    cf.setHostName("localhost");
    cf.setPort(1415);

    cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);

    cf.setQueueManager("TEST");
    cf.setChannel("TEST.CHANNEL");


    MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection)cf.createQueueConnection("mqusr","q@789945");

    MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    MQQueue replyQueue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///TEST.REPLY.QUEUE");
    MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(replyQueue);

    TextMessage receivedMessage = (TextMessage) receiver.receive(10000);
   String reponseMessage = receivedMessage != null ? receivedMessage.toString() : "";
```

Comment: To receive the message you need to issue connection.start() before doing a receive.receive(10000)

Comment: yes its working fine now.@subbaraoc

Comment: yes i can able to read the message but, the messages are not stable in the Queue, it not reducing the count.@subbaraoc

Comment: Working now i corrected Thank you @subbaraoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To receive the message you need to issue connection.start() before doing a receive.receive(10000) –